# Exit function in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new to laravel\PHP framework so please forgive my ignorance. I have a laravel API.Currently this API has a post & get endpoint. Whenever a request is sent to POST endpoint, it triggers an infinite loop. In postman, when I send a request, the cancel button in postman helps me to 'cancel the request'/stop.My UI has a 'RUN' button, basically it triggers my post endpoint, just like the send btn in postman. I wanted to know, how can I include an exit function. Do I need an entirely new function and its route?so that, when this imaginary 'stopServer' function is called, it stops/exits my infinite loop function? if so, how can I approach it? This is my store function:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        while(true) {
            $generator = rand(10,20);
            $date = new DateTime();
            $date = $date->format('h:i:s');
            $date = strtotime($date);
            $case1 = $date ;
            $case2 = $date ;
            $case3 = $date ;

            if( $case1 % 30 == 0) { 
                $case1 = date('h:i:s', $case1);
                $response = "Reported". " " .$generator ." " ." running at" ." " .$case1;

                $Tasks = TaskType::create([
                    "program_time" => $case1,
                    'event' => 'START',
                    "message" => $response,
                    "actual_time" => $case1,
                    "display_message" => $response,
                    'colors' => '#fff'
                ]);
                        sleep(1);
                        continue;
                        return $Tasks ;
                       
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (true)` is an infinite loop. You can exit it using [break](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

```
while (true) {
    ...

    break;
}
```

It is useful when waiting for something to happen but you don't exactly know the number of iteration that will get you there.

Comment: Yes, break would be helpful. In my case, I want my loop to continue as long as a user does not invoke a stop/exit the function to stop my infinite loop. I am using axios to make requests to my server.My UI is a reactjs app. In it I have a RUN button which triggers the infinite loop.  I have a STOP button too, currently it does nothing because that is where I am stuck. I want to make a request to my server from my UI STOP btn,  and have it call a 'stopServer' function which will terminate my infinite program.But I do not know how to approach writing such a function.

Comment: What if someone doesn't press that button and then he leaves the browser?

Comment: That is a situation I honestly had not considered. But I think I will cross that bridge when it comes to it. Its not impossible but it is challenging. Thanks.

Comment: I think, need to consider using client-side rather than server-side. You can use `setInterval` to repeat the same job until the user finally stops it.